# Inheritance in classes. C++

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

Let's say I am creating a tree, and I have a class of Node and a class of Cars.

```
   class Cars : public Node{
     ....
    };
```

If I have an object all ready defined as a Node, but I now want it to make it a Car as well, how would I do it?

Thank you !

Comment: Assuming I'm understanding you correctly, I'm afraid you cannot do what you want.  But you can make a *new* Cars object from your existing Node object by defining a conversion constructor for the Cars class that specifies how to make Cars objects out of Node objects.

Comment: Create a object for Cars class and call the methods in Node class through Cars object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest thing you can do is to supply a conversion constructor for your `Cars` class and create a new instance:

```
class Node
{
    // stuff goes here
};

class Cars : public Node
{
public:
    // other constructors, destructor, members, etc.
    Cars(const Node& node)
    {
        // copy node data into the Node portion of the car
    }
};

int main()
{
    Node n;
    Car c(n);
    return 0;
}
```

If you create it as a `Node` first, you cannot *magically* change it to a `Car` without creating an actual `Car` instance and copying the data into it.